# Tensorflow's app Camera Images are Blurry

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, android-camera, tensorflow-lite

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

What I achieve w/ my tensorflow app:

[image]

**Background:**
I'm using TensorFlow lite application that works badly because the images that are produced w/ the flash on are blurry and many similar white objects can't be distinguished. (The images are taken in a sort of a cup, which is a closed environment, this is why the flash is always on)

**If you want to reproduce the project, you can follow the instructions below:**

**Set up the working directory**

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/examples.git
```

**Open the project with Android Studio**

**Open a project with Android Studio by taking the following steps:**

1. Open Android Studio. After it loads select " Open an existing
   Android    Studio project".
2. In the file selector, choose examples/lite/examples/image_classification/android from your
   working directory to load the project.

In `LegacyCameraConnectionFragment.java`, in the function “`onSurfaceTextureAvailable`
“

Add in line 90~ this code is added to turn on the flash all the time (it's off by default):

```
List<String> flashModes = parameters.getSupportedFlashModes();
if (flashModes.contains(android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH))
{
  parameters.setFlashMode(parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
}
```

More info. about installation can be found here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/image_classification/overview#example_applications_and_guides

**What I tried:**

First, I tried tweaking the camera parameters:

```
            previewRequestBuilder.set(
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
                CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_MACRO);

            previewRequestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE,
                    CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

        parameters.setFlashMode(parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
        parameters.set("iso","100");
        parameters.setJpegQuality(100);
```

Then,

I've tried to implement autofocus w/ the following code (Which seems to do some focus, but still the image almost stays the same)

```
 private Camera.AutoFocusCallback myAutoFocusCallback = new Camera.AutoFocusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAutoFocus(boolean arg0, Camera arg1) {
      if (arg0) {
        LegacyCameraConnectionFragment.camera.cancelAutoFocus();
      }
    }
  };

  public void doTouchFocus(final Rect tfocusRect) {
    try {
      Camera mCamera = LegacyCameraConnectionFragment.camera;
      List<Camera.Area> focusList = new ArrayList<Camera.Area>();
      Camera.Area focusArea = new Camera.Area(tfocusRect, 1000);
      focusList.add(focusArea);

      Camera.Parameters param = mCamera.getParameters();
      param.setFocusAreas(focusList);
      param.setMeteringAreas(focusList);
      mCamera.setParameters(param);

      mCamera.autoFocus(myAutoFocusCallback);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      float x = event.getX();
      float y = event.getY();
  Rect touchRect = new Rect(
          (int) (x - 100),
          (int) (y - 100),
          (int) (x + 100),
          (int) (y + 100));


  final Rect targetFocusRect = new Rect(
          touchRect.left * 2000 / previewWidth - 1000,
          touchRect.top * 2000 / previewHeight - 1000,
          touchRect.right * 2000 / previewWidth - 1000,
          touchRect.bottom * 2000 / previewHeight - 1000);

  doTouchFocus(targetFocusRect);
}

return false;
```

}

Third,
I tried checking some repos:
First repo is Camera2Basic

```
https://github.com/googlearchive/android-Camera2Basic
```

This repo produces the same bad results.

Then I tried OpenCamera's source code which can be found in `source-forge.net`:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencamera/files/test_20200301/
```

And the app produces really good results, but after a few days I still couldn't figure out which part should I take from there to make this work. I believe it has to do w/ the focus, but I wasn't able to understand how to take the code from there.

I also watched some YouTube videos and went over 10 posts here about Android's Studio Camera API v1 and v2 and tried to fix it on my own.

I've no idea how to continue, any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: How did you take the initial picture that shows the result you want to have?

Comment: Why aren't you using `CameraConnectionFragment.java` from the guide instead?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a **very old** implementation of the Camera API in `LegacyCameraConnectionFragment`, which is [deprecated](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera). You should [use](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary) `android.hardware.camera2`, which is being used in the other tensorflow example, [CameraConnectionFragment](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/image_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/CameraConnectionFragment.java). Recently, CameraX was released to Beta, and there would probably be fewer examples for you to follow online, but some people are [enjoying](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ftof12/should_i_use_camerax_or_camera2/) it already. More info about cameraX [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kuv8uK-5CLY).

Looks like `CameraConnectionFragment.java` is already using optimal [settings](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/63ee35adcc3e3dd2d228bc3283e27f6a1e2158ab/lite/examples/image_classification/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/classification/CameraConnectionFragment.java#L467) for you?

> ```
> // Auto focus should be continuous for camera preview.
> previewRequestBuilder.set(
>     CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE,
>     CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AF_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
>     // Flash is automatically enabled when necessary.
>     previewRequestBuilder.set(
>        CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_AUTO_FLASH);
> ```

---

**PS:** I don't think you should hard-code or even 'fine-tune' your camera settings so that it only works in very small cases. Let the API do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: for OpenCamera, switch everything to manual and then see if you can find a combination of flash, shutter speed, focus mode, and ISO that does what you expect; then you could try to reproduce those parameters in your code.

Also, I would suggest to use the Camera2 API in the future, as it allows more fine-grained control over some parameters. See if you could rather use `CameraConnectionFragment` instead of `LegacyCameraConnectionFragment`.

Addendum: OpenCamera saves all parameters in an image's EXIF data, so you could just look up the parameters for the "good" image using any decent image viewer.

Comment: Hi, I looked at OpenCamera, but it doesn't seem that just the combination of these values help, I did try to implement a delayed flash too, and tweak many of the parameters like focus, ISO, and many more, it doesn't seem to help. Any more ideas Florian? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you upload the original picture at the top of your post somewhere so I can look at the EXIF data? You could also try to set a manual focus point.

Comment: P.S. I'm kind of trying to guess what you want to achieve, which is identifying medication doses in some sort of 3D printed container, correct? In that case, I think you should look for a fixed combination of flash, focus, exposure etc. and not for anything automated, as the environment is decidedly unusual.